# How to hide "Share", "Copy Link", "Copy to" buttons in my site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx, modern-experience, modern-team-site

I'm using SharePoint Online modern UI.

And, I want to hide `Quick edit, Sync, Export to Excel, Power Apps, Automate, Share, Copy Link, Copy to` from my site.

Please check below picture:

[image: this is my question]

I found the easy solution about `PowerApps, Automate, Sync` buttons in below URLs:

1. https://mbangert.de/hide-power-apps-and-power-automate-flow-in-sharepoint-online
2. https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/08/disable-sync-button-in-sharepoint-online.html

But I can't find solution other buttons.

I don't want to use SPFx if possible, but is there no choice except to use SPFx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide "Quick Edit" button, you can set **Quick property editing** to **No** at List Advanced settings:
[image]

[How to Disable Quick Edit in SharePoint?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/01/how-to-disable-quick-edit-in-sharepoint.html)

For "Share", you can consider using permission to limit the access.

For other buttons, no. You can vote up the [User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/36611854-hide-document-library-toolbar) about this similar requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking now there's a project in SPFx extensions on github for hide commands by Russell Gove. It uses CSS Selectors for hiding the commands by referencing them from a list. More on ReadeMe.md link below. Didn't work for ECB menu.

[README.md](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/main/samples/js-command-hide-commands/README.md)

[Hide Commands](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/js-command-hide-commands)

Answer (score 0):

You can now hide command bar options (at the top) from list/library using SharePoint JSON view formatting.

Use JSON like below in view formatting to hide "Power Apps" option:

```
{
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "powerApps",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Similarly, you can add more keys to same JSON as per your requirements. Currently below keys are supported:

```
'new'
'newFolder'
'newWordDocument'
'newExcelWorkbook'
'newPowerPointPresentation'
'newOneNoteNotebook'
'newFormsForExcel'
'newVisioDrawing'
'upload'
'uploadFile'
'uploadFolder'
'open'
'share'
'copyLink'
'download'
'rename'
'copyTo'
'moveTo'
'delete'
'edit'
'comment'
'editNewMenu'
'powerBI'
'powerBIVisualizeList'
'automate'
'automateCreateRule'
'automateManageRules'
'powerAutomate'
'powerAutomateCreateFlow'
'powerAutomateSeeFlows'
'powerAutomateConfigureFlows'
'aiBuilderCreate'
'aiBuilderGoto'
'aiBuilder'
'alertMe'
'newLink'
'integrate'
'manageAlert'
'powerApps'
'powerAppsCreateApp'
'powerAppsSeeAllApps'
'powerAppsCustomizeForms'
'viewDocumentUnderstandingModels'
'versionHistory'
'openInImmersiveReader'
'classifyAndExtract'
'checkOut'
'checkIn'
'undoCheckOut'
'properties'
'pinItem'
'exportExcel'
'exportCSV'
'export'
'editInGridView'
'exitGridView'
'sync'
'uploadTemplate'
'addTemplate'
'openInOfficeOnline'
'openInOfficeClient'
'addShortcut'
'pinToQuickAccess'
'unpinFromQuickAccess'
```

**Documentation**: [Command bar customization syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting)

---

Currently there is no SharePoint out of the box option available for hiding options under context menu (...). So, you may need to do it using custom CSS/JS injection using SPFx.

However such DOM manipulations using CSS/JS injection are not supported/recommended by Microsoft.

Check if it helps: [How to hide buttons on the item context menu in SharePoint 365 Modern Experience](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304623/how-to-hide-buttons-on-the-item-context-menu-in-sharepoint-365-modern-experience/304627#304627)