# How to hide buttons on the item context menu in SharePoint 365 Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, context-menu

I've been able to easily hide any toolbar button by using "Format current view" and adding the JSON.

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
"commandBarProps": {
"commands": [
    {
      "key": "download",
      "hide": true
    },
   {
      "key": "copyLink",
      "hide": true
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

But how do I edit the Item context action menu?  I would also like to know if it is possible to hide the whole menu.

[image: Context action menu]

Also, I currently don't have SharePoint Designer, but I could get it if needed. I've seen some info around for SPFx, but I have never done anything in SPFx. A need a simple solution if there is one, lol. Also, on my wish list is getting rid of the Share button.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you cannot hide individual context menu options using JSON formatting. You can only customize/hide options from command bar at the top.

You can hide "Share" option from command bar using `` as key like:

```
{
    "key": "share",
    "hide": true
}
```

**Documentation**: [Command bar customization syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting)

---

You can hide complete context menu from **list** view using two methods:

**Method 1 - SharePoint OOTB**:

In SharePoint list, Title column has three different variants:

- Title
- Title (linked to item)
- Title (linked to item with edit menu)

So, you can use plain "Title" column in your list view to hide context menu.

**Method 2 - JSON formatting**:

You can add simple JSON formatting on Title column like below to hide context menu:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

While using JSON formatting, you will loose all OOTB functionality formatting for Title column including default click which open display/view form of list, you can get it back using JSON formatting on Title column like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "defaultClick"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-field-underline"
  }
}
```

---

**Update from comments**:

As you are using document library, you have to apply column formatting on **Name** column instead of **Title** column: :

Format option:

[image]

Then go to "Advanced mode":

[image]

Copy-paste above JSON and click "Save":

[image]

You can apply additional styling as per your requirements. Check below documentation for more information:

1. [Use Column formatting in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [JSON formatting-syntax-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)

Comment: I added the code below to my "No Context Menu" view > Format current view. "Share" still displays in the top toolbar, even for my Read only/Visitor role.                                              
 {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "share",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Sharing Permissions set to: Only site owners can share files, folders, and the site. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Method 1:  Please note, I am a newbie and I need more information to try your answer. Regarding Method 1.  I added the "Title" column to my view, the Context Menu no longer displays. Yea! Thanks. Is there JSON to get it to populate with the File Name?

Comment: Method 2: I Also tried to use Method 2. I went to Library Settings > more library settings > clicked on the "Title" column > then pasted the code from the 2nd gray box into the Column Formatting box > clicked OK and nothing changed. Also, when I went back to Column Formatting the code I pasted doesn't even display. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you are using document library, you have to apply JSON formatting on "Name" column. Check updated answer for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much for the additional info! Adding the JSON to the column works great!!!!

Comment: When I added the JSON a strange thing happened to the font, it became smaller. Any way to fix that problem?

Comment: It changed from Segoe 14px to 12px.

Comment: You can add CSS styling via JSON as per your requirements. check documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference

Comment: Thank you for the link to Syntax. This works to fix the font: {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
"style": {
    "font-size": "14px"
},
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "defaultClick"
  }
}